# Rails ActiveRecord Scope that is the "opposite" of another scope, or is users that "lack" a property

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, named-scope

I have a model for user.rb, in which I define a scope for `admins`, which is users that have the role of admin through a permissions table.

```
has_many :permissions
has_many :roles, :through => :permissions
```

The scope works like this:

```
scope :admins, joins(:permissions).merge(Permission.admin_permissions)
```

I'd also like to make a scope called `non-admins` or something like that, which is all users that do NOT have the admin role.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An easy way, which **would not be performant** for a lot of users:

```
admin_user_ids  = User.admins.map(&:id)
non_admin_users = User.all.reject { |u| admin_user_ids.include?(u.id) }
```

Comment: A quicker way of the first line would be to do 'admin_user_ids = User.admins.pluck(:id)'

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have an inverted SQL query, you will have to do it yourself manually. There is no built-in ActiveRecord solution.

```
scope :admins, joins(:permissions).merge(Permission.where("permissions.admin = true"))
scope :non_admins, joins(:permissions).merge(Permission.where("permissions.admin = false"))
```

If there are a lot of scopes or they are complex, consider excluding them by id:

```
User.where("id not in (?)", User.admins.pluck(:id))

# or if you are already using admin records
admins = User.admins
User.where("id not in (?)", admins.map(&:id))
```

Depending on number of rows and complexity of the original query, this could be slower or faster than the previous way.

Comment: For your scope solutions, i've the problem that when I do a join and merge, it will only take into account objects that have related objects created. In my case i'm not dealing with User+Permission. So I need to return a set for all objects with related objects with a false property, and all objects without related ones. And your way doesn't work to me