# Ruby on Rails - Scope to exclude tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search method where I want to give the user the option to exclude `Cases`, the model I'm searching, that have certain topics. The `Search` model has two separate many-to-many relationships with `Topics`, set up like so:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ViewersHelper

  has_many :included_topics, through: :including_topics, source: :topic
  has_many :excluded_topics, through: :excluding_topics, source: :topic
  has_many :including_topics
  has_many :excluding_topics
```

To search for cases including certain topics, I used this code.

```
  ids = included_topics.pluck(:id)
  cases = cases.includes(:topics).where('topics.id' => ids)
```

What would be the opposite of this query to get the excluded topics working?

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406669/rails-activerecord-scope-that-is-the-opposite-of-another-scope-or-is-users-th), I tried the following:

```
  ids = excludes_topics.pluck(:id)
  cases = cases.includes(:topics).where('topics.id NOT IN (?)', ids)
```

But rails gives me the following error from that query:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Searches#show
Showing ../app/views/searches/show.html.erb where line #6 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: topics.id: SELECT  "cases".* FROM "cases" WHERE (topics.id NOT IN (2)) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

line #6 is just the first line where the `@cases` variable that the search is performed upon in referenced

Comment: Try `cases.includes(:topics).where('topics.id NOT IN (?)', ids).references(:topics)`

Comment: That query doesn't give me an error, but it also doesn't return the desired results. On a query of 100 cases, where cases 2 & 3 are tagged by the topic I'm excluding, it's returning cases 1 & 3, but I want 1 & 4-100. Case 3 is tagged by two topics, which is why it's showing up.

Comment: Try this `cases.includes(:topics).where.not('topics.id' => ids)`

Comment: That one has the same problem as the first. I combined your suggestions with my code to make a result that uses two queries. Not sure if there's a more elegant way to do it

Comment: I would suggest renaming this question, as "tags" is not a Rails term, to my knowledge. Do you mean attributes?

Comment: @Paven, please put your comments into an answer, and explain your reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`ids = excludes_topics.pluck(:id)
cases = Case.joins(:topics).where('topics.id NOT IN (?)', ids)`

Comment: @Ben, I would suggest working with this solution, as it has one fewer query than yours.

Comment: I would even try to use just one query but I didn't test it:
`Case.joins(:topics).where('topics.id NOT IN (?)', excludes_topics.select(:id).to_sql)`

Comment: If that comment works, please add it! Fewer queries mean faster page loads (indirectly)

Comment: This one is returning the same results as the responses to my original post. On my test, I have 100 cases. case 2 & 3 have the topic I want to exclude, case 3 has another topic as well. I want the results 1, 4 -100 but that query returned 1 & 3

Comment: Perfect Answer.. but be sure while working with `NOT IN` about the excluded topic ids should be present always. because if there no excluded topics it will return blank array for `ids`. and `NOT IN` with blank array will return empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I created using two queries:

```
  ids = excludes_topics.pluck(:id)
  included_cases_ids = Case.all.includes(:topics).where('topics.id' => ids).pluck(:id)
  cases = cases.where.not('id' => included_cases_ids)
```

Comment: Is this your final solution? Also, it is best to use as few queries as possible

Comment: I know it's best to use fewer queries, so this might not be my final solution. Should remove this as an answer and just edit my comment to include this solution, since it might not be final?

Comment: I think it is best to edit your answer saying that this is a working solution. Since StackOverflow is Q&A, _never_ include "answers" in the question body. It clutters it up and makes it difficult what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, if your final solution is _similar_ to one provided by another user, but not _the same_, then I suggest upvoting any answer that helped, and attribute to that user in your answer.